# can't drag and Drop iboutlets xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, iboutlet

how are you. 
I'm having a problem on `XCODE-9`. I can't drag and Drop from storyboard to a file to create an `IBOutlet`. For example, I want to create a reference from an image View and so I Press control and try to Drop into the code but it doesn't happen anything.

Comment: use mouse right click, it works.

Comment: I still have the problem. It's supposed that when I drag and Drop my Image View there will be a line and then I put the reference on the code but I can't do that.

Comment: For Image Views you need to go to the Attributes inspector and select 'User Interaction Enabled' before you can cntl-drag. It is unselected by default.

Answer (score 0):

Check the correct file is opened. If not then firstly drag and drop your file to assistant Editor in Xcode

Comment: I'm with the correct file, MainStoryBoard.swift opened in the Assistant Editor, but still having problems I can't Drop the reference to the Swift file and if I try to do it writening this I get an error.